# How do I get NFS on Linux to export a folder to OS X with OS X's user IDs so I can cp -a from Linux to OS X?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac-osx, nfs, file-sharing

I have Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 on one computer and OS X 10.11.2 on another. I want to migrate files from the Ubuntu installation to the OS X installation but preserving permissions.

Currently the strategy I am attempting is to export my home directory over NFS, mount it from the Mac, and `cp -a` the files off the mount. I know that on OS X UIDs and GIDs are assigned differently than on Linux. On Linux my UID/GID is 1000/1000 and on OS X my UID/GID is 501/20.

From what I can gather, having this in my `/etc/exports` should be sufficient to get my Linux files showing up as 501/20 on the Mac:

```
/home/pietro/   <Mac's IP>(rw,sync,all_squash,no_subtree_check,insecure,anonuid=501,anongid=20)
```

and mounting on the Mac with

```
mkdir /tmp/q
sudo mount -t nfs <Linux's IP>:/home/pietro /tmp/q
```

However, when I mount this way, `ls -l` on the Mac tells me that the file permissions are still 1000/1000.

I have also tried:

- `no_root_squash`
- `anonuid=1000,anongid=1000`
- removing `no_subtree_check`
- removing `sync`
- `echo N | sudo tee /sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping` followed by `sudo nfsidmap -c`
- `NEED_IDMAPD=yes` in `/etc/default/nfs-common`
- `-o resvport` on the Mac

all to no avail.

So my question is: how do I configure NFS so that when I `ls -l` on the Mac side I get 501/20 as the owner/group, so I can safely `cp -a`?

Alternatively, am I using the wrong tool for the job and is there a better way? I need to preserve the other Unix permissions, so SMB does not seem to be an option. I'm also unwilling to risk changing the UID/GID of the OS X account.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to just use rsync, which [as of version 3.1.0 has options for doing what I want](https://superuser.com/questions/671011/how-to-arbitrarily-map-user-group-ownerships-in-rsync). I needed to get the latest rsync as Apple still ships an ancient version with OS X, but after that it was a matter of just doing

```
rsync3 --usermap 1000:501 --groupmap 1000:20 -a -v pietro@<Linux's IP>:/home/pietro/<path> <dest>
```

Thanks anyway!

**UPDATE** (for the benefit of Googlers) Vice versa works too, also from the Mac!

```
rsync3 --usermap 501:1000 --groupmap 20:1000 -a -v <src> pietro@<Linux's IP>:/home/pietro/<path>
```

`<path>` didn't seem to like spaces, but I might be doing somehting wrong...